# Вывод ajax json

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Не могу понять где косяк,кучу раз так делал, а сейчас не работает.

обработчик `polygon_output.php`

```
include 'database.php';
$STH = $DBH->query('SELECT * from polygon');  
$STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
while($row = $STH->fetch()) {  

$data= json_encode(
    array(
        'name'=>$row['name'], 
        'polygonpoints'=>$row['polygonpoints']
    )
);
echo $data;

}
```

**js**

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: 'polygon_output.php',
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(data) {

                console.log('[' + data + ']')

          }
    });
```

При заходе на `polygon_output.php` выводит json ,все нормально, а вот js нет

Comment: А пропустить data через eval не пробовали?

Comment: @Михаил вы хоть знаете что делает `eval`? и зачем оно там нужно?

Comment: что выдает лог? вы это приведите в вопросе, и еще кроме `success` внедрите в код `error: function(err){}`.

Answer (score 1):

В `polygon_output.php` добавь заголовок, что это `json`

```
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
```