# Не выдает объект в ответе ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

Формирую json

```
include ('config.php');
$STH = $DBH->query('
        SELECT 
            date, 
            new_users_count
        FROM
             H
        WHERE
             date BETWEEN "2018-10-01" AND "2018-10-19"');  

            $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
                    while($row = $STH->fetch()) {  
                    $data= json_encode(
                     array(
                        'date'=>$row['date'],
                         'new_users_count'=>$row['new_users_count']
                            )
                        );  
                         echo $data;

                            }
```

если напрямую зайти на этот php выдно что данные в json формате

затем пытаюсь получить

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType:'json',
  url: "serverscript/output.php",
  success: function(json) {
    console.log(json);
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log("ERROR", this);
  }
 });
```

Выдает ошибку

```
error:function()
arguments:null
caller:null
length:0
name:""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не отменяете стандартную отправку формы на сервер. Страница перегружается до того, как приходит ответ на ajax-запрос. Поэтому в консоли пусто.

---

Хорошо, добавьте в вызов ajax-a обработчик ошибок:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  dataType:'json',
  url: "serverscript/output.php",
  success: function(json) {
    console.log(json);
  },
  error: function() {
    console.log("ERROR", this);
  }
 });
```

---

А-а-а. Стоп. Все понятно.

Вы выводите в цикле куски JSON-a, но, склеенные вместе в ответе на запрос, они не являются правильным JSON-ом. Соберите сначала все данные, которые надо вернуть, в массив, а потом, после цикла, обработайте их `json_encode`-ом перед вызовом `echo`.

---

Кстати, год назад Вы уже сталкивались с этой проблемой:

[Вывод ajax json](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/727695/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-ajax-json)

Comment: Если в php сделать просто echo "test"; все будет хорошо или вывод echo  $row['new_users_count'] тоже проблем нет

Comment: @zkolya А-а-а. Стоп. Все понятно.

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо. Поправил,заработало!

Comment: @zkolya На здоровье. Про "галочку" слева от ответа Вы знаете ).